# Skobbler not picking up content from meta-folder in PreinstalledMaps (iOS)

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am trying to make an offline application with a bundled map. The map is running in `SKConnectivityMode.Offline`, so I have put the map data in: `SKMaps.Bundle/PreinstalledMaps/v1/20150413/package`

I have also copied the metadata into:
`SKMaps.Bundle/PreinstalledMaps/v1/20150413/meta`

The problem is that the data in the meta-folder is not picked up, and the map does not render. I tried to copy the meta-folder into the Library/Caches-location of a Simulator app, and then the map renders as expected.

A workaround I had in mind was to copy the meta-folder into the Library/Caches-area when the application is started the first time - but it will lead to double storage of files, and seems a bit dirty.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

The version of the Skobbler API is 2.5.

Comment: Most probably there's an issue in the Bundle composition - please send you SKMaps.bundle to dev@skobbler.com and we'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem, with help from the API developers. The SKMaps.bundle was for some reason not being replaced in the application package by the build script, and I needed to run a Product->Clean from XCode.